# Spliting an array into individual arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i have a an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => bruce
    [1] => arju
    [2] => newu
    [3] => jack
    [4] => john
    [5] => kyle
    [6] => sam
    [7] => tim
)
```

i want to split the above array into multiple arrays 
eg: is show below

```
array
(
[0] => bruce
)

array
(
[1] => arju
)
```

Comment: where is siuth australia in your data?

Comment: You want to translate one array into N arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind if I ask why you would ever want something like this?

```
<?php

  $names = Array(
    'bruce',
    'arju',
    'newu',
    'jack',
    'john',
    'kyle',
    'sam',
    'tim'
  );

  for($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++){
    $name[] = array($i => $names[$i]);
  }

  foreach($name as $key => $val){
    echo $key, ':<pre>';
    print_r($val);
    echo '</pre>'
  }

  // or you could use array_chunk
  // http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php
  print_r(array_chunk($names, 1));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
<?php
$newarr1 = $_SESSION['arrt1'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarr1);
echo '<pre>';
$newarray2 = array();
$i = 0;

while ($i < sizeof($newarr1))
{
    $newarray2[] = array(
        "person_id" => $i + 1,
        "person_name" => $newarr1[$i]
    );
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Edit:

```
<?php
$newarr1 = $_SESSION['arrt1'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarr1);
echo '<pre>';
$newarray2 = array();
$i = 0;

while ($i < sizeof($newarr1))
{
    $newarray2[] = array(
        $i => $newarr1[$i]
    );
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: The sample was just a patter . you wont name people as state. and yeah sry for that 0.. and also sample changed

Answer (score 1):

[PHP array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) might help 
For breaking the arrays in individual arrays you can use

```
$a = array_chunk($input_array, 1); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will give your result.....